# Springboot Refused to apply css "because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type"

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-security, mime

spring boot refuses to display my images and my css style sheets which are in my folder /static/style and /static/img it worked however at the beginning, and I think it comes from SpringSecurity, I however authorized access to these resources.

In the google console I have this message: Refused to apply style from 'address/style/style.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled .

Here are snippets of my code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean // (2)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**", "/h2-console/**", "/webjars/**", "/img/**", "/style/**", "/dist/**", "/css/**",
                        "/js/**", "/img/**", "static/**")
                .permitAll() // (3)
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // (4)
                .and().formLogin() // (5)
                .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")// (5)
                .permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")// (6)
                .permitAll().and().httpBasic().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin(); //// (8)
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new DbUserLoginService(); // (2)
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() { // (2)
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

I've also heard of this line of code: <security:intercept-url pattern="/ressources/**"access="permitAll" /> but I have no idea how to comment it works or where to place it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that you have to configure in a specific way. From most restricted (or specific privileges) to permitAll/anonymous; you can trying commenting the (3) step from your configuration or reordering the configuration as a suggested.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security) an example, you can check that the steps are from specific privileged to less specific.